# Is the Ubuntu on Dell machines stock Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, oem

I'm interested in a Dell machine with Ubuntu pre-installed (just for the sake of knowing it's 100% Linux compatible)

The Ubuntu that's being installed on Precision and XPS13 models, is that a stock Ubuntu or did Dell add some specific things to make it work with their hardware?

If i wanted to switch to Fedora or Elementary and then back to Ubuntu at some point in the future, it would be reassuring to know that a stock Ubuntu would just work without major tweaking.

Comment: I don't think they modify the OS is any way, as they fully expecting you to reinstall it right after purchase. At best they have some of their custom software installed.

Comment: Thanks @muru, it seems they do make some modifications including some of their own repositories. It seems that they include a restore partition which allows you to factory restore it, so it might be easy to experiment with other distros and just factory reset it if these other distros don't work as well.